# How can I make code wait for a GUI to finish?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I know there is a similar question asked in relation to Matlab, but it hasn't helped me for Java. I am writing a GUI for a program where the results of one GUI frame are necessary for another GUI frame - I have simplified my problem to that below:

I have a GUI  `JFrame`  with a  `JTextField`  that, when a button is pressed, returns the contents of the field as a string.

Further down the static main method, this string is used for other methods - although in this demonstration its just put into a print statement.

The problem I am having is that the code is not waiting for completion of the GUI (aka someone to press the button and trigger an event) before continuing on to the next statement - thus in this demo problem its causing "null" to be printed and in my larger problem it causes null to be passed to other JFrames (and throw an exception).

What I have learnt on line is that this is due to the "multi-threaded" nature of Swing - and every time I create a Swing component, it runs in its own thread to enable the rest of the code to continue - however in this case, I don't want the rest of the code to continue, what I think I want (I may be wrong) is all the other threads to wait for the current Swing thread to finish and give a result which can be used further down the program.

What code can I use in order to make the code pause until the GUI's `JButton` has been clicked?

I am aware that one solution to this is to "nest" the dependent code inside the  `ActionListener`  part of the code, but in larger projects this gives me large amounts of nested code, which doesnt seem a good thing.

The demo problem code for the main method is here:

```
public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Testing runningClass = new Testing();
    String message = null;

    JGetString getString = new JGetString();
    message = runningClass.initiateListener(getString);

    System.out.println(message); // How can I make this wait until getString
                                    // has closed?

}

private String initiateListener(JGetString window) {
    buttonListener listener = new buttonListener(window);
    window.addActionListener(listener);
    return listener.returning;

}

public class buttonListener implements ActionListener {

    JGetString getString;
    String returning;

    public buttonListener(JGetString getString) {
        this.getString = getString;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String returning = getString.returnString();
        this.returning = returning;
        getString.setVisible(false);

    }

}

}
```

And the code for my GUI which extends  `JFrame`  is here :

```
public class JGetString extends JFrame {
private JTextField textField;
private JButton btnGet = new JButton("Get");

public JGetString() {
    textField = new JTextField();
    getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(btnGet, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}


public void addActionListener(ActionListener act) {
    btnGet.addActionListener(act);

}

public String returnString() {
    return textField.getText();
}


}
```

Sorry for such a long question and large blocks of code - and thanks!

Comment: u may possibly use built-in method for input [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Arvind already pointed out in the comment: A common approach when you want to "wait for the GUI" are *dialogs*. In particular, *modal* dialogs. Predefined standard dialogs can be created with the utility methods of `JOptionPane`. More information can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

A Dialog usually is not a "real window". It does not have a representation in the task bar, for example. If you want to create a real `JFrame`, and wait for it to be closed, things may become a bit fiddly: The *creation* of the frame should actually be done on the event dispatch thread.

So in order to find an appropriate solution, you should have a *really* clear idea about which thread is responsible for what, and which thread should wait for which other thread at which point.

By the "responsibilities", I refer to the role that each class plays. For example: It could be a feasible (and probably easier) solution to let the `ActionListener` play the active role here. The `ActionListener` could call a method in the main class, and pass the string to this method. This would allow an easy synchronization between the main thread and the Event Dispatch Thread (possibly, but preferably not, with `synchronized`, `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.

However, another solution, where the `ActionListener` remains "passive", and the actual string is still obtained from the `JGetString` instance, is sketched here: It introduces a `Waiter` class that only encapsulates a `CountDownLatch` and thus allows waiting for the button to be pressed. But **NOTE** that depending on your long-term goal and the general structure and intentions behind your program, there may be more appropriate solutations.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WaitForGUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WaitForGUI waitForGUI = new WaitForGUI();

        String message = waitForGUI.getStringFromGUI();
        System.out.println(message); 

    }

    private JGetString getString = null;    
    private Waiter waiter;

    public WaitForGUI()
    {
        // Create the synchronization aid that will
        // allow waiting for the `JGetString` to 
        // be closed
        waiter = new Waiter();

        // Create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                getString = new JGetString();

                ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(getString);
                getString.addActionListener(listener);

                getString.addActionListener(waiter);
            }
        });
    }

    // This method will block until the button in 
    // the `JGetString` was pressed.
    String getStringFromGUI()
    {
        waiter.waitFor();
        return getString.returnString();
    }


    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        JGetString getString;

        public ButtonListener(JGetString getString)
        {
            this.getString = getString;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            getString.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private static class Waiter implements ActionListener
    {
        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            latch.countDown();
        }

        void waitFor()
        {
            try
            {
                latch.await();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}

class JGetString extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnGet = new JButton("Get");

    public JGetString()
    {
        textField = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(btnGet, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener act)
    {
        btnGet.addActionListener(act);

    }

    public String returnString()
    {
        return textField.getText();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will look into this and the aforementioned Dialogs !